# Where does the colloquial word for the angle grinder ("угловая шлифовальная машина") come from?

Tags: этимология

Why is the angle grinder ("угловая шлифовальная машина") called "болгарка"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0):

> Русское разговорное название этого инструмента — «болгарка» — возникло в СССР в 1970-х годах, когда здесь появились первые его образцы, выпущенные именно в Болгарии[3], на предприятии «Спарки Элтос» под торговой маркой «Eltos» в городе Ловеч[4]. Сейчас слово «болгарка» можно встретить даже на ценниках в магазинах. Иначе как в странах бывшего Советского Союза такое название этого инструмента нигде не употребляется[5]. В Болгарии же УШМ называется «русская».

Comment: fun fact - the English swear word "bugger" derived from Bulgar as well - but of course for completely different reasons - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bugger

Comment: @shabunc as well as "vulgar"... a lot older word derived from the same ethnonym.

Comment: "В Болгарии же УШМ называется «русская»" => plain wrong. "Ъглошлайф" or "флекс" in Bulgarian.

Comment: @fraxinus: Это к тому, насколько можно доверять произвольным интернет-источникам, включая Википедию.

Comment: @fraxinus was that taken from German perchance? шлайф sounds a whole lot like [schleifen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schleifen), assuming a pronunciation similar to Russian Cyrillic.

Comment: @0xC0000022L exactly. "Шлайф" is an established German loanword in Bulgarian with exactly the same meaning. "Ъгъл" is bulgarian for "угол" and in fact quite similar even to the English "angle".

Comment: @fraxinus vulgar has nothing to do with bulgar

Comment: @Anixx I am Bulgarian. It is a common knowledge here, but may as well be completely wrong.

Answer (score -3):

I heard or read (I don't remember now) it comes from word "burglar" because angle grinder is good for cutting metal doors, bars and so on.